# Is it ok to use vbox instead of figure for floating elements?

Tags: floats

I started using vbox instead of the figure command for tikz drawings and for text that I do not want to be over the next page like so:

```
\documentclass[oneside, pdftex, a4paper, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left = 3cm, right = 3cm, top=3cm, bottom = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
%\linespread{1.5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-.2ex}%
                                    {0.5ex \@plus0.2ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}
\makeatother
\title  {Mathematics 1\\Assignment 3}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Assignment 3}
\subsection{1a i) Find the area of $\triangle$ PQR, giving your answer to 3 significant figures}
\bigskip
\vbox{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){P}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
    \tkzDefPoint(2.8,2){Q}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){angA}
    \tkzDefPoint(2.8,0){S}
%     \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center P angle 35](R)
%     \tkzGetPoint{Q}
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center P angle 35](angA)
    \tkzGetPoint{angB}
    \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and 0](P,R)
    \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and 0](P,Q)
    \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and 0](R,Q)
    \tkzDrawSegment[dotted](Q,S)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,S,Q)
    \tkzDrawArc(P,angA)(angB)
    \tkzLabelPoints(P,R,S)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](Q)
    \tkzLabelLine[below](P,R) {8 cm}
    \tkzLabelLine[midway,sloped,above](P,Q) {7 cm}
    \tkzLabelAngle[right](angA,P,angB) {$30^\circ$}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\bigskip
\parindent=0
\vbox{
    To find the area we use formula for right triangles:\\ 
    \begin{align*}
        \mbox{Area}&=\frac{1}{2}(PQ)(QS)\\
        \mbox{Area}&=\frac{1}{2}(8)(QS) \\
    \end{align*}
}
\vbox {
    But first we need to find QS using the sine operator:\\
    \begin{align*}
        sin30^\circ&=\frac{QS}{7}\\
        QS&=(sin30^\circ)7\\
        QS&=3.5\mbox{cm}
    \end{align*}
}
\vbox {
Now that we found QS we apply the area formula for a right triangle:\\
    \begin{align*}
        \mbox{Area}&=\frac{1}{2}(8)(3.5)\\
        \mbox{Area}&=\frac{1}{2}(8)(3.5)\\
        \mbox{Result: Area}&=\underline{14.0\mbox{cm}^2}
    \end{align*} 
}
```

Basically vbox is a raw TeX command, and I am wondering if is ok to be using it in this way.

Comment: Use `minipage`, but I don't know why you'd want it. There's nothing wrong in an image placed in a `center` environment, for instance. Note that `\parindent=0` will raise an error.

Comment: Given that you have a `\bigskip` before `\centering` the tikz diagram why not using `\begin{center} ...\end{center}`?

Comment: "Is it OK" is a bit vague. What do you mean? Is it possible? yes. Is it good practice? Perhaps not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `\vbox` (anywhere in a latex document) and don't use `\\` outside the alignment like this  `les:\\` you will remove all the flexible glue around displays and have inconsistent spacing between the elements. Getting good spacing between two vboxes is quite tricky as they align the reference point on the baseline of the bottom row, hiding all other structure. Normally the spacing between two paragraphs automatically adjusts if there are descenders in the bottom row of the first and tall characters in the top row of the second, but if they are in a vbox tex does not use information about the top row of the second box.